Show that function $x\to \int_{[a,b]} f(x,y)dy$ is continuous.
Let $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ be compact, $D$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $f:D\times [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ have properties: (1) for every $y\in [a,b]$, the function $x\to f(x,y)$ is continuous (2) for every $x\in D$, the function $y\to f(x,y)$ is Lebesgue measurable, (3) there is a Lebesgue integrable function $g: [a,b]\to [0,\infty)$ such that $|f(x,y)|\le g(y)$ for all $x\in D, y\in [a,b]$.
Show that function $x\to \int_{[a,b]} f(x,y)dy$ is continuous.

My proof is as follows. Clearly, for every $h>0$,
$$
|F(x+h)-F(x)|=|\int_{[a,b]} f(x+h,y)dy-\int_{[a,b]} f(x,y)dy|\le \int_{[a,b]}|
f(x+h, y)-f(x,y)|dy
$$
Since $x\to f(x,y)$ is continuous, then $\lim_{h\to 0}|f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)|=0$.
Since $|f(x+h, y)-f(x,y)|\le 2g(y)\in L_1[a,b]$, then by Dominated convergence theorem
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}|F(x+h)-F(x)|\le \lim_{h\to 0}\int_{[a,b]}|
f(x+h, y)-f(x,y)|dy=0
$$
Hence, $F$ is continuous.
Does this proof look good?

You can just use the dominated convergence theorem.

@温泽海 Is the proof ok?
